# add a new row to a table with ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have a bit problem. The fact is that I realize that every time I add a line, it takes into account the other adds. Ie, if I add a line, OK, that is inserted below that clicked. But if I want to add below the new, it actually adds two lines and so on. Any help ? This is my code

```
<script>


$(".insertRow").live('click', function () {

    var vref = '@Url.Action("RecordEntryRow", "Layout")';
    var obj = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: vref,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            var u = $(obj).parents(".record:first.")[0];
            $(u).after(html);
        }
    });
    return false;

});
```

Comment: "record" is the class of row in the table. And "RecordEntryRow" is the name of my method and "Layout" the name of my controller.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a test uppon your edited question.
Everything works as expected:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var i = 0;
                $(document).off('click', '#td').on('click', 'td', function(e) {
                    $(this).parent().after('<tr><td>Append ' + i + '</td></tr>');
                    i++;
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="td" style="border: 1px solid red;">
                    Test
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, my question is to add a row under the row cliqued . No at the end of the table. Means, you are at "this" row and when you click on a "plus button", it adds a new row just under the row clicked.

Comment: @JoëlMulaj'i Ok, can you give me a example of your table?

Comment: At this level, every time I add a line, it adds. But when I want to add a second, he has in fact all the lines I added before and instead of adding a single line, it actually adds the number of lines added previously

Comment: Webprogrammer i add my code as an answer for my question. You can see my table there. Does it helps you ?

Comment: Yes, actually you are missing the closing `</tr>`

Comment: Dont worry, it does not appears there, but in my code it is in. </tr> exists

Comment: @JoëlMulaj'i see my updated answer. You can also shorten your code by doing so: `$(obj).parent("tr").after(html);`

Comment: Webprogrammer, unfortunately, i have the same problem. It seems that once I added a new line, it duplicates the lines several times instead of just one

Comment: @JoëlMulaj'i did my example work for you? Please do a console.log(html) in your AJAX-success so you can check if your response is wrong or something else in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr class ="record">

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Records")) { 


    <td> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, new List<SelectListItem>{
                                                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "titre en gras", Value="Titre_Gras"},
                                                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "titre normal", Value="Titre_Normal"},
                                                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "titre minime", Value="Titre_Minime"},
                                                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "titre italique", Value="Titre_Italique"},
                                                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "item", Value="Item"},
                                                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Separateur", Value="Separateur"},
                                                    }) </td>
    <td> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contenu) </td>
    <td> <a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('tr').remove();"><img src="~/Content/images/red-delete-button.jpg" width="25" height="25" /></a></td>
    <td> <a href="#" class="insertRow" ><img src="~/Content/images/add_button.png" width="20" height="20" /></a> </td>

}
```